# how to set correct from email address in javamail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am trying to send email using following method. It works fine but I am facing one issue. 
I want to use a different "sender" address, then the address I used for gmail authentication.
so in following code I set "message.setfrom" - as sender@comp.com but still when the receiver gets the email , the from address is user@gmail.com.

please help me in identifying what am I doing wrong here , and how can I have the from address correctly set to "sender@comp.com".
Appreciate your help!
Thank you!!

```
    private void sendMail(String textBody, String subject) {
    try {
        final String messageSender = "user@gmail.com";
        final String pass = "pass";
        /** get my properties **/
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        /** get default session object **/
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(messageSender, pass);
            }
        });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        String[] to = {"abc@test.com"};
        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        message.setSubject(subject);

        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Fill the message
        messageBodyPart.setText(textBody);

        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@comp.com"));

        //send message
        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail will stop you doing that. Best you can do is change the reply to.

Comment: Thank you!! I added replyto as well, the replyto works fine. so its a gmail restriction. :( . may be I will switch to yahoo then.